# Properties of triangles with integer sides and area

Tags: combinatorics, triangles, combinatorial-geometry, discrete-geometry, oeis

OEIS sequence [A051518](https://oeis.org/A051518) describes

> There exists a triangle of perimeter $n$ having integer sides and area.

And begins

```
12, 16, 18, 24, 30, 32, 36, 40, 42, 44, 48, 50, 54, 56, 60, 64, 66, 68, 70, 72, 76, 78, 80, 84, 88, 90, 96, 98, 100, 104, 108, 110, 112, 114, 120, 126, 128, 130, 132, 136, 140, 144, 150, 152, 154, 156, 160, 162, 164, 168, 170, 172, 174, 176, 180, 182, 186, 190, 192, 196, 198, 200, 204
```

---

Uncharacteristically, the OEIS sequence doesn't have any comments describing the sequence. I'd like to know more about this sequence and the underlying triangles. For example:

- Must all of the terms be even?
- Are there infinitely many even numbers that do not appear in the sequence?
- Are there infinitely many terms $a(n) = a(n - 1) + 6$?
- How many such triangles exist for a given $n$? (e.g. There are at least 4 non-congruent triangles with a perimeter of $a(6)=36$ and integer area.)
- What is the asymptotic growth of such multiplicity?
- What is the ratio of right vs isosceles vs scalene triangles with perimeter less than $N$?
- Can all triangles with integer perimeter and area be described with integer coordinates? (e.g. the $7$-$15$-$20$ triangle can be described with $(0, 0), (12, 16), (0, 7)$.)

---

Here's what I know (and I may have missed some cases)

```
a(1)  = 12 describes the 3-4-5    right     triangle.
a(2)  = 16 describes the 5-5-6    isosceles triangle.
a(3)  = 18 describes the 5-5-8    isosceles triangle.
a(4)  = 24 describes the 6-8-10   right     triangle (scaling of a(1)).
a(5)  = 30 describes the 5-12-13  tright    triangle.
a(6)  = 32 describes the 10-10-12 isosceles triangle (scaling of a(2)) or
                     the 4-13-15  scalene   triangle.

a(7)  = 36 describes the 10-13-13  isosceles triangle or
                     the 10-10-16 isosceles triangle (scaling of a(3)) or
                     the 9-12-15  isosceles triangle (scaling of a(1)) or
                     the 9-10-17  scalene   triangle.

a(8)  = 40 describes the 8-15-17  right     triangle.
a(9)  = 42 describes the 7-15-20  scalene   triangle or
                     the 13-14-15 scalene   triangle.

a(10) = 44 describes the 11-13-20 scalene   triangle.
a(11) = 48 describes the 15-15-18 isosceles triangle (scaling of a(2)) or 
                     the 10-17-21 scalene   triangle or
                     the 12-16-20 right     triangle (scaling of a(1)).
```

---

Perhaps this is too open ended to be a good question for MSE.

Is anything known about this sequence? Or is anything known about these sorts of triangles?

Comment: [Heron's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) may offer some insight. For instance, the semiperimeter features prominently in some forms of the formula, that can probably be used to show that $n$ must be even.

Comment: Ah, indeed Heron's formula proves that the semiperimeter must be an integer—and so the perimeter must be even.

Comment: You might want to see [Heronian triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heronian_triangle). Also, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_triangle).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Must all of the terms be even?

Yes, as [Arthur](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/15500/arthur) suggested, [Heron's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) states that if the sides of the triangles are $a$, $b$, and $c$, with semiperimeter $s$, then the area is
$$A = \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}.$$
If the semiperimeter were not an integer, then $A$ would not be rational—thus the semiperimeter is an integer and the perimeter is even.

#### Are there infinitely many even numbers that do not appear in the sequence?

Yes! For example, $2p$ does not appear in the sequence for any prime $p$.
By Heron's formula, in order for the area $A$ to be an integer, $s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)$ must be square. But this means (without loss of generality) that $s-a = p = a$. However, this violates the [triangle inequality of Euclidean geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Euclidean_geometry).

In any case, I created OEIS sequence [A305703](https://oeis.org/A305703), which lists the even numbers that do not appear in the sequence.

#### Are there infinitely many terms $a(n)=a(n−1)+6?$

I don't know. But Zhang's proof of bounded gaps between primes implies that $a(n)=a(n-1) + k$ for *some* $k$.

#### How many such triangles exist for a given n? (e.g. There are at least 4 non-congruent triangles with a perimeter of a(6)=36 and integer area.)

I don't know, but I've added this to the OEIS as [A305717](https://oeis.org/A305717). It looks like this may not have a lot of structure.

#### What is the asymptotic growth of such multiplicity?

This is a good question for the aforementioned OEIS sequence.

#### What is the ratio of right vs isosceles vs scalene triangles with perimeter less than N?

Again, I don't know, but this could also spin-off into a few good OEIS sequences.

#### Can all triangles with integer perimeter and area be described with integer coordinates? (e.g. the 7-15-20 triangle can be described with (0,0),(12,16),(0,7).)

Yes! Paul Yiu had a nice article in the March 2001 edition of *The American Mathematical Monthly* called [Heronian Triangles Are Lattice Triangles](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2695390)
 with a neat proof.